# Python function: user input to get positive integer using assert

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, integer, assertions

Is it a bad thing to use **asserts** to validate user inputs? Or should I keep using an **if statement** in case the number isnt positive?

Code with assert statement:

```py
def get_posit_n() -> int:
    from locale import atoi
    while True:
        try:
            number = atoi(input('Enter a positive integer:\n-> ').strip())
            assert (number > 0)
            return number
        except (ValueError, AssertionError):
            print('Number must be an positive integer...\n')
```

Code with if statement:

```py
def get_positive_integer(msg: str = "Enter a integer value: ") -> int:
    from locale import atoi
    while True:
        try:
            number: int = atoi(input(msg + '\n-> ').strip())
            if number <= 0:
                continue
            return number
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid value!\n')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intended use of `assert` is in test code,
or to validate internal preconditions.

To validate user input, the common recommendation is to raise a `ValueError`.

There is no point in raising an error (with `assert` in the posted code) only to catch it right after.

Also, `AssertionError` is not meant to be caught,
it's meant to let it crash the program.

Taking the best parts of the examples:

```
from locale import atoi


def input_positive_integer() -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            number: int = atoi(input('Enter a positive integer:\n-> ').strip())
            if number <= 0:
                print('Number must be a positive integer...\n')
                continue
            return number
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid value!\n')
```

Comment: Thank you, janos!

Comment: What does `atoi` do? "Attempt to Integer"? Is it basically forcing/expecting the input to be an integer?

Comment: @BruceWayne It appears to be a standard function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.atoi

Comment: @Teepeemm I will look into it, thanks. I wonder why `int()` wouldn't work ...but that's a separate question.